# How to remove a specific word from a file name and convert it to kebab-case in a VSCode snippet?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to create a VSCode snippet that removes a specific word from a file name and converts it to kebab-case. For example, if the file name is "MyAppPlugin.ts", I want the snippet to convert it to "my-app". I've found and tried the following expression in my snippet that convert file name to kebab-case:

```
${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(^[A-Z])|([A-Z])/${2:+-}${2:/downcase}${1:/downcase}/g}
```

To remove `Plugin` i modify snippet as follow:

```
${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(Plugin)//(^[A-Z])|([A-Z])/${2:+-}${2:/downcase}${1:/downcase}/g}
```

However, this expression doesn't seem to remove the word 'Plugin' from the file name. Can someone please help me modify this expression to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: `Plugin` is caputured into Group 1, remove `${1:/downcase}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: if this is the follow-up of your previous question why not mention this also in that question, wonder what would be the next question if somebody solves this for you. Your problem is that you don't have much momentum in your progress

Comment: I don't understand your comment, because I haven't asked a similar question before! I don't understand why you are mad at me. If you don't know the answer, or if you don't want to share your knowledge, don't argue, just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

After receiving a hint from @Wiktor_Stribiżew in the comments, I began to ponder how regex grouping works. It became apparent to me that I had been using regex grouping incorrectly. Instead of using `(Plugin)//`, I should have used `(Plugin)|`, which now becomes group 1. With this correction, I can now proceed with the other groups: `(Plugin)|(^[A-Z])|([A-Z])`.

This is the working snippet:

```
${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(Plugin)|(^[A-Z])|([A-Z])/${3:+-}${3:/downcase}${2:/downcase}/g}
```